# Trouble with awk match

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I'm having trouble trying to match an exact string with awk.

My intent is to search a csv for a match and get the line number of that match.  So if I search for "1.1.1.2" in the below file I want it to return "1"

**CSV**

```
[apache@JBLAMPS001 tmp]$ cat test.csv
node2,1.1.1.2
node20,1.1.1.20
node21,1.1.1.21
node22,1.1.1.22
node102,1.1.1.102
node202,1.1.1.202
```

**Things I've tried**

```
[apache@JBLAMPS001 tmp]$ awk '/'1.1.1.2'/ {print NR}' test.csv
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

---

```
[apache@JBLAMPS001 tmp]$ awk '/\y'1.1.1.2'\y/ {print NR}' test.csv
1
5
```

---

```
[apache@JBLAMPS001 tmp]$ awk '"^1.1.1.2$" {print NR}' test.csv
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Does anyone know how I can structure this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Regex, you need to use proper modifiers and anchors to get only the desired match(es). In your case, the Regex pattern `1.1.1.2` (`.` means any single character BTW) will match all lines, hence the result. The last one is `awk '"^1.1.1.2$" {print NR}'` is not how you put a Regex pattern in `awk` -- you need to use either `//` or `$<field> ~ <pattern>`.

---

Here is how you can get your desired result:

- Regex way: escape all `.`s to treat them literally, add `$` to match end:

  ```
  awk '/1\.1\.1\.2$/ {print NR}' test.csv
  ```
- String manipulation: printing the record number if the `,` followed by any horizontal whitespace separated last field is `1.1.1.2`:

  ```
  awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '$NF == "1.1.1.2" {print NR}' test.csv
  ```

Comment: @Jesse_b Pass the variable to `awk`: `awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' -v ipaddr="1.1.1.2" '$NF == ipaddr {print NR}' test.csv`

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes, i know. What i meant is: `awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' -v ipaddr="$ipaddr" '$NF == ipaddr {print NR}' test.csv`

Answer (score 0):

```
ip=1.1.1.2; sed -ne "/,${ip//./\\.}\$/=" yourIPfile
```

Where we are escaping the dots `.` and give that to the sed command `=` which will display the matching line number.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try good old `grep`:

```
grep -wFn 1.1.1.2 yourIPfile
```

or

```
ip=1.1.1.2 ; grep -wFn $ip yourIPfile
```

In both cases, output is

```
1:node2,1.1.1.2
```